# Why the -b(binary) option doesn't work in vim?

Tags: vim

As vim doc said, I can use the [*-b*](http://www.cs.csubak.edu/docs/vim/starting.html#-b) option to open a binary file.

---

```
-b      Binary mode.  File I/O will only recognize <NL> to separate
        lines.  The 'expandtab' option will be reset.  The 'textwidth'
        option is set to 0.  'modeline' is reset.  The 'binary' option
        is set.  This is done after reading the vimrc/exrc files but
        before reading any file in the arglist.  See also
        |edit-binary|.  {not in Vi}
```

---

I use this command to open vim:

```
$ vim --cmd 'set et' -u NONE -b
```

---

I type this command to view options:

```
:set et? bin?

  expandtab
  binary
```

---

The `et`(`expandtab`) option wasn't reset. Why?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Perhaps I'm reading this wrong, you are setting the 'expandtab' option as an argument and '-b' resets it prior to that.

Comment: @Fredrik. To make the question clear. I didn't post my `.vimrc`. I think this command contains what I want to say.

Comment: The documentation also states that `modeline` is turned off, but checking the option has the same result as `et`.

Comment: I've made a simple `vimrc.debug` which only contains `set et`. Then run `vim -b -u vimrc.debug`. The result is not as doc said.

Comment: looks like a bug and you have posted the workaround `-u NONE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the issue is, simply, that --cmd -c or `+cmd` arguments are executed after processing the other flags. This makes sense, as it would not effectively do anything otherwise.

```
 :verbose set et?
```

would tell you exactly that. In case you need a workaround for your particular sample `vim +'set binary'` (unlikely since et != binary)

You are right on the docs for --cmd. So it comes down to the *order* in which command line flags are interpreted, which is basically 'undefined'. Although

> This is done after reading the vimrc/exrc files but before reading any file in the arglist

could be taken to imply 'before processing other command line arguments'.

**Note** The '+' commands essentially go with specific files and are (AFAICT) processed in the order in which they appear, even when intermixed with filename arguments.

Comment: `--cmd` is executed before `vimrc`, and `-b` is executed after `vimrc`, `-c` is executed after buffer loaded.

Comment: @kev I think that is accurate.